# Openlayers TMS map tiles bad position

Tags: openlayers, tms

i get a png map from google tiles url (http://mt{0123}.google.com/vt/lyrs=m&hl=fr&x=!x&y=!y&z=!z) using bigmap2 (http://bigmap.osmz.ru/) with zoom and bounding box coordinates, i use following command to prepare that map and get tiles:

For this example bounding box is -11.250000, 36.597889, 16.875000, 52.482780 and png dimensions are 1280 x 1024.

gdalinfo map.png

gdal_translate -of VRT -a_srs EPSG:4326 -gcp 0 0 -11.250000 52.482780 -gcp 1280 0 16.875000 52.482780  -gcp 1280 1024 16.875000 36.597889 map.png map.vrt

gdalwarp -of VRT -s_srs EPSG:4326 -t_srs EPSG:3857 map.vrt map2.vrt

python gdal2tiles-multiprocess.py --zoom=4 map2.vrt

I tried using "standard" gdal2tiles.py from debian package too.

This generate a folder with subfolders containing tiles and a webpage viewer with using openlayers.

On that page main layer is from openstreetmap and my TMS layer is shown as overlay.

For "small" maps i have no problem but for large areas as europe or world TMS layer position is bad, layer is shift up (see attachment) while OSM layer is good.

Here is the code i use:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      <head>
        <title>map2.vrt</title>
        <meta http-equiv='imagetoolbar' content='no'/>
        <style type="text/css"> v\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
            html, body { overflow: hidden; padding: 0; height: 100%; width: 100%; font-family: 'Lucida Grande',Geneva,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif; }
            body { margin: 10px; background: #fff; }
            h1 { margin: 0; padding: 6px; border:0; font-size: 20pt; }
            #header { height: 43px; padding: 0; background-color: #eee; border: 1px solid #888; }
            #subheader { height: 12px; text-align: right; font-size: 10px; color: #555;}
            #map { height: 95%; border: 1px solid #888; }
        </style>
        <script src="http://www.openlayers.org/api/2.7/OpenLayers.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var map;
            var mapBounds = new OpenLayers.Bounds( -11.25, 36.5978889026, 16.874999903, 52.48278);
            var mapMinZoom = 5;
            var mapMaxZoom = 7;

            // avoid pink tiles
            OpenLayers.IMAGE_RELOAD_ATTEMPTS = 3;
            OpenLayers.Util.onImageLoadErrorColor = "transparent";

            function init(){
            var options = {
                controls: [],
                numZoomLevels: 7,
                projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"),
                displayProjection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
                units: "m",
                maxResolution: 156543.0339,
                maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(-20037508, -20037508, 20037508, 20037508.34)
                };
            map = new OpenLayers.Map('map', options);


            // create OSM/OAM layer
            var osm = new OpenLayers.Layer.TMS( "OpenStreetMap",
                "http://tile.openstreetmap.org/",
                { type: 'png', getURL: osm_getTileURL, displayOutsideMaxExtent: true, attribution: '<a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a>'} );
            var oam = new OpenLayers.Layer.TMS( "OpenAerialMap",
                "http://tile.openaerialmap.org/tiles/1.0.0/openaerialmap-900913/",
                { type: 'png', getURL: osm_getTileURL } );

            // create TMS Overlay layer
            var tmsoverlay = new OpenLayers.Layer.TMS( "TMS Overlay", "",
                {   // url: '', serviceVersion: '.', layername: '.',
                    type: 'png', getURL: overlay_getTileURL, 
                    isBaseLayer: false
                });
            if (OpenLayers.Util.alphaHack() == false) { tmsoverlay.setOpacity(0.7); }

            map.addLayers([osm, tmsoverlay]);

            var switcherControl = new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher();
            map.addControl(switcherControl);
            switcherControl.maximizeControl();

            map.zoomToExtent( mapBounds.transform(map.displayProjection, map.projection ) );

            map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.PanZoomBar());
            map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition());
            map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.MouseDefaults());
            map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.KeyboardDefaults());
        }

        function osm_getTileURL(bounds) {
            var res = this.map.getResolution();
            var x = Math.round((bounds.left - this.maxExtent.left) / (res * this.tileSize.w));
            var y = Math.round((this.maxExtent.top - bounds.top) / (res * this.tileSize.h));
            var z = this.map.getZoom();
            var limit = Math.pow(2, z);

            if (y < 0 || y >= limit) {
                return "http://www.maptiler.org/img/none.png";
            } else {
                x = ((x % limit) + limit) % limit;
                return this.url + z + "/" + x + "/" + y + "." + this.type;
            }
        }

        function overlay_getTileURL(bounds) {
            var res = this.map.getResolution();
            var x = Math.round((bounds.left - this.maxExtent.left) / (res * this.tileSize.w));
            var y = Math.round((bounds.bottom - this.tileOrigin.lat) / (res * this.tileSize.h));
            var z = this.map.getZoom();

            if (mapBounds.intersectsBounds( bounds ) && z >= mapMinZoom && z <= mapMaxZoom ) {
               //console.log( this.url + z + "/" + x + "/" + y + "." + this.type);
               return this.url + z + "/" + x + "/" + y + "." + this.type;
            } else {
               return "http://www.maptiler.org/img/none.png";
            }
        }       

       function getWindowHeight() {
            if (self.innerHeight) return self.innerHeight;
            if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.clientHeight)
                return document.documentElement.clientHeight;
            if (document.body) return document.body.clientHeight;
                return 0;
        }

        function getWindowWidth() {
            if (self.innerWidth) return self.innerWidth;
            if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.clientWidth)
                return document.documentElement.clientWidth;
            if (document.body) return document.body.clientWidth;
                return 0;
        }

        function resize() {  
            var map = document.getElementById("map");  
            var header = document.getElementById("header");  
            var subheader = document.getElementById("subheader");  
            map.style.height = (getWindowHeight()-80) + "px";
            map.style.width = (getWindowWidth()-20) + "px";
            header.style.width = (getWindowWidth()-20) + "px";
            subheader.style.width = (getWindowWidth()-20) + "px";
            if (map.updateSize) { map.updateSize(); };
        } 

        onresize=function(){ resize(); };

        </script>
      </head>
      <body onload="init()">
        <div id="header"><h1>map2.vrt</h1></div>
        <div id="subheader">Generated by <a href="http://www.maptiler.org/">MapTiler</a>/<a href="http://www.klokan.cz/projects/gdal2tiles/">GDAL2Tiles</a>, Copyright &copy; 2008 <a href="http://www.klokan.cz/">Klokan Petr Pridal</a>,  <a href="http://www.gdal.org/">GDAL</a> &amp; <a href="http://www.osgeo.org/">OSGeo</a> <a href="http://code.google.com/soc/">GSoC</a>
        <!-- PLEASE, LET THIS NOTE ABOUT AUTHOR AND PROJECT SOMEWHERE ON YOUR WEBSITE, OR AT LEAST IN THE COMMENT IN HTML. THANK YOU -->
        </div>
        <div id="map"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript" >resize()</script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

I read a lot about openlayers but can't find something helping me.

I don't understand why, for some maps it works, and not for other while i made tiles the same way for all.

I'm a beginner, thanks for help.

[image]